# Setting the HttpOnly attribute for the NodeJS cookie header

Tags: node.js, http, cookies

I'm trying to figure out how to set the HttpOnly attribute for the set-cookie header, specifically for native NodeJS.

Right now, I have this code, but it doesn't work because I can still access the cookies with client side javascript.

```
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['HttpOnly']);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To set cookie, you need to specify cookie name and value, which is missing in your code. That's why it does not work. Example code would be:

```
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'foo=bar; HttpOnly');
```

If you want to set multiple cookies, some with `HttpOnly`, some without. The code would be:

```
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['foo=bar; HttpOnly', 'x=42; HttpOnly', 'y=88']);
```

According to [Node.js HTTP document](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html), there is no global `HttpOnly` configuration, which makes sense, as normally you may need some cookie client readable.

Comment: Oh I see. I misinterpreted the NodeJS documentation, but you cleared it up. Thanks for your help!